# CakePHP - Wrap radio and label with div and fieldset using Form->radio

Tags: html, cakephp

Any cakePHP Guru who can help me out with this one. I am trying to generate this markup block in a loop. The idea is that I do not have to write each fields manually, whilst keeping the project cake oriented.

This is the Html I want ( basically) :

```
<fieldset>
   <div>
      <label><span></span></label>
      <div>
         <div>
            <label><input type="radio"></label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label><input type="radio"></label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

simple right? (wrong)

I am trying to use the Form helper like so

```
foreach($my_questions as $key => $quest){
        $attributes = array(
            'between' => "<label><span>{$quest}<span><label>",
            'separator' => '</div><div class="radio inline">',
            'format' => array('after', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'before', 'error' )
        );
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo $this->Form->radio($key, $options,$attributes);
        echo '</fieldset>';
}
```

I am sure I am missing something or I simple can't do it like this. Any help is appreciated. The sooner the better. Thanks a heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) for your fieldset. So create a file like `app/View/Elements/radio_fieldset.ctp`, add your fieldset HTML to it, put a foreach in it to loop over an array you want to push in, for example:

```
<fieldset>
   <div>
      <label><span><?php echo $question; ?></span></label>
      <div>
         <?php foreach ($options as $optionId => $option): ?>
         <div class="radio inline">
             <label>
             <?php echo $this->Form->input($optionId, array(
                 'value' => $option,
                 'type' => 'radio'
             )); ?>
             </label>
         </div>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Make sure that in your Controller, you set all the questions/options.
Then from your View, push in the question and options to the element, something like this:

```
echo $this->element('radio_fieldset', compact('questions', 'options'));
```

The above code will surely need some tweaking to fit your specific situation, but it should give you an idea on how to approach this in a more "Cake-ish" way.

Comment: Nice approach! I still need to get a good feel to using elements in cake, and I know i'm missing out!  I managed to do what I needed as I described in my answer. And feedback on that? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The closest I got is this :

```
    echo '<fieldset><div>';
    echo '<label><span>'.$quest.'</span></label>';
    echo $this->Form->input($key, array(
    'before' => '<div>',
    'after' => '</div>',
    'between' => '--between---',
    'separator' => '</div><div>',
    'legend' => false,
    'options' => array('Yes', 'No'),
    'type' => 'radio'
    ));
    echo '</div></fieldset>';
```

I am not entirely sure if its the best way, or correct for that matter, but it works for me and practically does what I need! The trick is to set legend to false to remove the automagic for creating a fieldset and  legend, then be able to set the opening and closing tag for the separator.

And here's the result! `Gotta Love Cake`

```
<fieldset>
   <div>
     <label><span>Got any questions?</span></label>
     <div class="input radio">
       <div>
         <input type="hidden" name="data[q_3]" id="q_3_" value="">
         <input type="radio" name="data[q_3]" id="Q30" value="0">
         <label for="Q30">Yes</label>
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="radio" name="data[q_3]" id="Q31" value="1">
         <label for="Q31">No</label>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```